# Why QAbstractItemView::dragEnterEvent is always accepted?

Tags: c++, qt, qabstractitemview

Why `QAbstractItemView::dragEnterEvent` doesn't​ check model's `canDropMimeData` method? This results in incorrect 1-pixel area along widget boundary which is always "positive-drop" without taking into account if model can actually accept data after all? Source code contains comment "Drag enter event shall always be accepted, if mime type and action match.", but it doesn't explain anything.